# Getting parents that have children in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get a list of only parent models that have child models. What's the best way to accomplish this in Laravel?

Normally I would do this using a left inner join but this seems like the type of thing Laravel would handle magically with the hasMany relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

> When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship. For example, you wish to pull all blog posts that have at least one comment. To do so, you may use the has method:
>
> ```
> $posts = Post::has('comments')->get();
> ```